# razor is fully and partially displaying data from database in same foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view

I am having a crazy problem I have not encountered before.  I have some razor in a view generating labels and radio buttons from database columns.

Here is the example of my looping in the view:

```
 @foreach(var item in Model)
            {
                foreach (var cat in item.PainCategories)
                {
            <h3><b>@Html.Label(cat.Title, new { cats = cat.Title.Distinct() })</b></h3>
                    <div align="left" style="font-size:small">
                    @foreach(var tri in item.Triages)
                    {
                        if (cat.Id == tri.PainCategoryId)
                        {
                        @Html.RadioButton(tri.PainCategory.Title, tri.Order)
                        @Html.Label(tri.Description )<br/>
                        //Error is happening in the line above
                        }
                    }
                    </div>
                }
            }
```

This is an example of my database table:

```
Id     Order         Description
1       1               Desc 1
2       2               Desc 2
3       3               Desc 3
4       4               Desc 4
5       5               Desc 5
6       6               Desc 6
```

So my problem is that it will populate all of the try.Order for the radio buttons in the inner foreach loop.  But when it gets to the tri.Description.  It only prints the first 4 descriptions and the rest dont show up.  I've tried using @Html.Display and the same thing occurs. I know it is making it through each foreach because the order will make it to 6 but the description stops at 4.  Weird problem, if anybody could give me some advice it would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if you need to see more code too (such as controller or model).  Thank you.

----Edit----

So the controller returns a list of JSON objects that are stored into DefectsVM model and displayed in a datatable in the view.

The Controller:

```
var requestDef = new RestRequest("defect", Method.GET);
            requestDef.AddHeader("id", id);
            requestDef.AddHeader("key", Key);
            requestDef.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            var responseDef = Userclient.Execute(requestDef) as RestResponse;

            List<DefectsVM> defects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DefectsVM>>(responseDef.Content);
            IEnumerable<DefectsVM> defectsToReturn = defects.Where(d => d.ProjectId == item.ProjectId);

            foreach(var i in defectsToReturn)
            {
            i.PainCategories = db.PainCategories.Where(p => p.CompanyId == compId).Where(t => t.CompanyId == compId).ToList().Distinct();
            i.Triages = db.Triages.ToList().Where(t => i.PainCategories.Any(cat => t.PainCategoryId == cat.Id));
            }


return View(defectsToReturn);
```

DefectsVM model:

```
public class DefectsVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public double UserPainIndex { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AssignedToId { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ReportedById { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<PainCategory> PainCategories { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Triage> Triages {get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: check the paincategoryid of the last 2 descriptions and see if they match the cat.Id

Comment: You sure are having a *lot* of problems with your project, I remember seeing similar bits of code so many times already on SO.

Comment: This is usually when you don't have a primary key properly defined in your model in EF.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yea group project and I am stuck doing all the work out of 5 people so I got a lot to learn lol.

Comment: Typical academia group project...

Comment: @failedprogramming And yes the decriptions PainCategoryId does match the PainCategory tables Id value

Comment: @intracept And the primary key is set to Id in the PainCategory table as well as a primary key on the Triage table at Id.

Comment: Is that reflected in your EF Model?  What do you get if you enumerate the Triage collection?  Does that give you your descriptions?

Comment: Maybe you can put a breakpoint in your controller action and check your model to see if it actually contains a descriptions for those 2 rows?

Comment: So when I go through the controller foreach funtion (I edited question) the i.Triages contains all of the triages and descriptions when iterating through the loop on the rows that are not being printed in the view.